# I can´t change session parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, parameters

I am following http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth to add an authentication method for my RoR app.

The Session controller can access and modify the params[:user_id] values. I can see that with the raise sessions[:user_id].to_yaml

However, I cannot modify those values on another page.

It does show the values on 
raise session[:user_uid].to_yaml
, but not on 
raise params[:user_uid].to_yaml

If thing the problem is that params should include the session has, and it is not there.

Please help, I´ve been fighting with this for days. Thanks.

PD: the whole code is on git@github.com:brunosan/papernote.git

PPD: If I clone and run the railscasts git repository and run it, it works. I went file by file to see differences and I can´t get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using `session[:user_uid]` in the SessionsController#create action but `session[:user_id]` elsewhere. Be certain to be consistent here.

Also, the session is a different store than the params so they won't contain the same values. If you are settings/getting the `user_id` it's best to always work with the session, not params hash.

Comment: Thanks man. After 2am one gets blind to such dumb errors. I really appreciate the help.